# Bug? ibidem in floats with the `floatrow`-package

Tags: biblatex, floatrow

When I use the `floatrow`-package with biblatex and a citation style that uses ibidem-tracking, usually, when I cite a publication twice, the second time the citation gets replaced with (ibid.) (or ebd. in Germany) indicating a reference to the same source as before.

Citing inside the caption of a floating object though, the full citation ***should*** show up always, instead of the (ibid.) short.

**This behaviour seems to be broken when using the `floatrow`-package instead of `float`.**

---

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

% Bibliography entries:
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@booklet{one,
    author = {Author One and Author Three and Author Four and Author Five and Author Six and Author Seven and Author Eight and Author Nine},
    title = {Testtitle 1.},
    date = {2018},
}
@booklet{two,
    author = {Author Two},
    shortauthor = {AOne},
    title = {Testtitle 2.},
    date = {2018},

}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   

\usepackage{mwe} % Example figure
\usepackage{graphicx} % Includegraphics command

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid,sortlocale=de_DE]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\usepackage{floatrow} % Creates a bug when used instead of float
\begin{document}

Here, I cite the publication a first time: \parencite{one}. Now, I cite it a second time, where ebd. shows up correctly. \parencite{one}.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[draft, width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{In this float caption, when I cite a third time, no ebd. should appear \parencite{one}.}
\end{figure}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output of this MWE:
[image: Buggy output of the MWE]

---

Can you confirm this? I guess this is not intended?
Is there a workaround for this? (I don't need a workaround ATM, but maybe someone else does)

And finally, if it is one, where should I report this as a bug? (since I have zero experience with bug reporting)

I am using MikTex on Windows 10, `floatrow` v0.3b, and `biblatex` v3.11.

Have a nice day! :)

Comment: I can confirm this, but I would call it expected behavior because basically the `[H]` option removes the floating ability of the figure (so the figure stays always in the flow of the text and ibidem could be right). Do you really need the floatrow package?

Comment: I just used `[H]` for the convenience of the screenshot. First, this also happens with `[h]` or `[b]`, and second, with `float` and `[H]`, it works just fine.

Comment: Yes, I know, I have tested it, hence I asked whether you really need the *floatrow* package. Most of the functionality may be achieved with other packages (which may be a bit more up-to-date). Concerning your question on bug-reporting: The package documentation contains an e-mail address, so you would use that.

Comment: No, I currently don't need the floatrow package, luckily. I just found this bug while it still was included in my preamble from a previous document and suddenly noticed this bugged behaviour of ebd. Thanks for your hint concerning the email address. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex` adds code to `\@floatboxreset` to disable citation tracking in floats. That happens in an `\AtEndPreamble` hook. The `floatrow` package effectively takes over `\@floatboxreset` and replaces it with `\FR@flboxreset`, the original definition of `\@floatboxreset` at the time of loading `floatrow` is retained saved and used as a basis for `\FR@flboxreset` later on. But that means that changes to `\@floatboxreset` that happen  after `floatrow` have been loaded are ignored or discarded.

There are several possible work-arounds for this. You could initialise `\FR@flboxreset` in `\AtEndPreamble` as well, if the `\AtEndPreamble` call comes after `biblatex`'s preamble definitions the modified `\@floatboxreset` will be picked up

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}   

\usepackage{duckuments} % Example figure
\usepackage{graphicx} % Includegraphics command

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{floatrow} % Creates a bug when used instead of float

\makeatletter
\AtEndPreamble{\let\FR@flboxreset\@floatboxreset}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Here, I cite the publication a first time: \parencite{sigfridsson}. Now, I cite it a second time, where ebd. shows up correctly. \parencite{sigfridsson}.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{In this float caption, when I cite a third time, no ebd. should appear \parencite{sigfridsson}.}
\end{figure}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The figure caption reads "Abbildung 1: In this float caption, when I cite a third time, no ebd. should appear (Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998)." with no ebd/ibidem]

Alternatively, one could execute

```
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\@floatboxreset
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {}
  {\blx@err@patch{floats}}
\makeatother
```

manually *before* loading `floatrow`.

---

#### Is this a bug? Whose bug is this?

This is a tricky. The behaviour does not seem to match the description in the `biblatex` documentation, so you may call this a bug. (I could try and wiggle my way out of this particular case because a `[H]` figure is not really a float any more and so I could argue that §4.11.5 *Trackers in Floats and TOC/LOT/LOF* of the biblatex documentation does not apply. That does not hold a lot of water since the problem persists even with non-`[H]` floats as long as `floatrow` is loaded.)

To get things like this right `biblatex` needs to meddle with many things that normally do not fall within the scope of a bibliography/citation package. LaTeX being LaTeX there is almost no guarantee that the code `biblatex` needs to patch is going to behave as expected with all class and package combinations.

I am fairly confident that `\@floatboxreset` is not the completely wrong command to patch into and I also believe that the cautious approach of patching the macro as late as possible has its merits. So I'm not sure if there is something `biblatex` could do better in this case except of course for checking for `floatrow` or patching `\FR@flboxreset`.

At the same time I don't think `floatrow` is really in the wrong here either.

Given that `floatrow` has not been updated since 2009 I'm not sure if you well be able to contact the maintainer. Plus I'm not exactly sure what `floatrow` should do better (sure, it could initialise  `\FR@flboxreset` later, ...).

You could also open an issue for `biblatex` at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues. It is possible to fix this on the `biblatex` side with relatively little effort. I personally don't find it that brilliant that `biblatex` has to have patches for so many different packages and classes, because maintaining these patches requires keeping an eye on possible changes in the code of the relevant packages and classes.